# How to setup context sharing between GPUImage and cocos2d to capture gameplay video

Tags: objective-c, video, cocos2d-iphone, instagram, gpuimage

I'd like to capture video from cocos2d gameplay in my app. I can just simply use glReadPixels, but it's very slow. I found out that GPUImage/GPUImageMovieWriter uses more advanced approach, but I have to setup context sharing between GPUImage and cocos2d

Anybody knows how to make that?

I've tried to push GPUImage's sharegroup into cocos2d, but I have no luck:

```
container = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(116, 37, 480, 640) pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 depthFormat:0 preserveBackbuffer:NO sharegroup:[[[GPUImageContext sharedImageProcessingContext] context] sharegroup] multiSampling:NO numberOfSamples:0];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a tool for that. Kamcord and others.

Comment: Yes, I know. We've tried Kamkord, but it has two issues: 1) sometimes video is just black. 2) video created in Kamkord is incorrectly cropped in Instagram. We contacted Kamkord support a few weeks ago, but they weren't able to solve our issues. I was able to make video using "CCRenderTexture" and solve Instagram issue, but as CCRenderTexture uses glReadPixels and it's very slow

Comment: have you tried the other libraries? There's at least one other though I can't remember its name.

Comment: Are you rendering to a texture within cocos2d? You need to somehow get your rendered scene into a texture for it to be usable by GPUImage, and then it needs to be provided to a GPUImageTextureInput. GPUImage doesn't do anything with content rendered directly to a view.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, yes, we also tried everplay without success. I would be happy if anybody can suggest me something else. For now I ended up with Brad Larson's suggestion to use FBO

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for the great effort on building GPUImage and sharing it with everybody, we use your library in other apps, and pretty happy with it. It has an GPUImageMovieWriter, which uses a more advanced technics than just glReadPixels, what can solve a problem with performance. I was hoping to build something as fast as Kamkord, but with your opensourced library, so I'm able to modify sources and solve the crop problem if needed. Do I correctly understand that there's no easy way to setup my OpenGL/cocos2d as a "source" for GPUImageMovieWriter?

Comment: what do you need the video for? If it's for a trailer and not something the user can do, then just use Reflector to record screen & audio via Airplay, works like a charm: http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

Comment: It's a feature for the "end-users", so the way is used for trailers isn't possible for us.

Comment: @Victor - Others have done this with cocos2d, so I know it's possible. The one thing you need to be able to do is to render to a texture. I'm sure cocos2d has a function to allow this. Once you have a texture containing your rendered scene, you can pass that into the framework to be recorded in a movie.